# Excel VBA - Add an array to a dictionary and search if it exists

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

Within a loop I would like to write values to a cell only if a string combination has not already been gone through.
So I am trying to create a dictionary containing an array (the combination of two string variables) and then to check if this combination already exists in the dictionary. My code is the following and I get the “Invalid procedure call or argument” error at the first line. Could you please help me solve this?

```
…

    If Not my_dict.exists(arr) Then           
                                With my_sheet.Cells(x, COL_DOC)   
                                    .Value = string1
                                End With
    
                                   arr = Array(string1, string2)
                                   my_dict.Add k, arr
                                   k = k + 1
        End If

…
```

Comment: This cannot be done in the way you try. **An array cannot be a dictionary key**. But, it can be a dictionary `Item`. If you will explain the context and what you try accomplishing I can show you a solution. In your specific case, you have to check the key:  `If Not my_dict.exists(k) Then`. Or make the key by joining the array: `If Not my_dict.exists(Join(arr, "|")) Then`, followed by `my_dict.Add Join(arr, "|"), arr`... Only due to the fact that the array has less items. You can load the key by iteration and the arrays (if many) as items. Then, you can compare a new one only by iteration.

Comment: You can also make a key from concatenation of the two involved cells value...

Comment: @FaneDuru, thanks for the reply. The context is the following: I have activities (string2) and output documents (string1). Because one activity can have many output documents, and also one document can be an output for many activities, I would like to write the result of one particular activity and one particular output document of it only once. I also tried checking for  “my_dict.exists(k)” like you suggest, but it does not do what I want, as there are many k’s but for different combinations.

Comment: I did not suggest to use `k`... I told you that `k` should be something to be accepted by the dictionary. If an array of only two elements, did ou try the real suggestion? `If Not my_dict.exists(Join(arr, "|")) Then`, followed by `my_dict.Add Join(arr, "|"), arr`...

Comment: @FaneDuru, I tried your suggestion and I get a type mismatch error at the first line now... I have declared the arr as variant.

Comment: Without seeing what you did, I can only say something else than you did a mistake... Not because the declaration. You do  not show me, at least, on what code line such an error appeared. At least, in your comment, if not editing the question and pasting it there. What does "first line" mean? How do you expect me to help? I played with such arrays and joining them many times... Such an error cannot be raised if you place strings in the array and use it **exactly as I suggested**. Did you use  `If Not my_dict.exists(Join(arr, "|"))`? If yes, are there an array named `arr`, containing strings?

Comment: Thank you. I found my mistake, I had not declared the string1 and string2 as String, and instead they were automatically understood by Excel as Variant. Now it works as needed!